# Move Email Server to Azure

Tags: email-server, hosting, azure, shared-hosting

I have a website hosted on a shared server at company X(BigRock/HistGator/GoDaddy etc.). They provide x number of email addresses as part of their hosting solution. I am planning to move my website to Azure and get rid of the hosting plan being used at company X. I would like to know how can I move my emails to Azure along with my website so that I can keep receiving and sending emails from my company account - xyz@x.com . If there's no way of moving the email server, what options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option is to build your own e-mail server using virtual machines which I don't recommend for your case. Microsoft e-mail solution is Exchange Online.

https://products.office.com/en-US/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans

To send bulk marketing e-mails from your site, you can use SendGrid from Azure Marketplace.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/sendgrid/sendgrid-azure/

Comment: This means, if I move my hosting to Azure, I will need to pay for my email services be it Microsoft or Google. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes and bear in mind that Azure is not a "hosting". Cloud computing is very different compared to regular hosting offers in the market.